# How can I properly set up cookie storage for different domains using Express and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, cors, session-cookies

```
const allowedOrigins = [
  "https://aabb.web.app",
  "https://aaa.bb.com",
];

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
      // allow requests with no origin
      // (like mobile apps or curl requests)
      if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
      if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
        var msg =
          "The CORS policy for this site does not " +
          "allow access from the specified Origin.";
        return callback(new Error(msg), false);
      }
      return callback(null, true);
    },
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'my secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    // cookie: {
    //   secure: true,
    //   sameSite: "none",
    // },
    store: new RedisStore({
      client,
      ttl: 60000,
    }),
  })
);
```

For example, the API server is located at https://aaa.bb.com/api, and my frontend is at https://aabb.web.app. I can log in, but it seems like it doesn't store the cookie. I get the same result when I uncomment the code 'cookie:{}'.

I tried various ways, including the following code:

```
cookie: {   
  secure: true,   
  sameSite: "none", 
},
```

I asked ChatGPT and Bard for a solution, but unfortunately, I haven't found a working solution yet."